# Very slow completion and code highlighting in Qt Creator

Tags: autocomplete, qt-creator, completion

I have Qt Creator 4.1.0 ubuntu 16.04. And I have problems with completion and code highlighting. I need to wait 3-4 secs(or more) for completion code and highlight key words.
What is wrong?
Qt Creator 3.6.0 is working normally.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm I observe the same problem on Windows 7 after upgrading from 3.6 to 4.1. I used to be able to tab complete function signatures and that no longer works which is annoying. Haven't tried 4.2RC yet to see if its fixed but I'll update this post once I do.